# New Mechanical Keyboard for Coding

Tags: keyboards

I've had a Corsair K70 RGB Pro for my laptop for quite a while. However, a recent accident with a coffee cup has, sadly, ended that one's use. I need a good, new, mechanical keyboard, which will be used for coding and a little bit of gaming. It must be wireless, and I don't really want a palm rest because my desk is a little too small for a laptop and a massive keyboard, I don't care about RGB, whether it has it or not, and it must be a Windows layout. I don't really mind on the size, but I'd prefer a TKL keyboard now, just because I never use the numpad. Any suggestions? UK QWERTY please Budget is anywhere up to ~£170

Comment: Hi e7eth, welcome to Hardeare Recs! Do you have any preference in terms of size/layout (e.g. full size/100%, 96%, 70%, 60%, ortholinear, ergonomic) or specific switches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Keychron Q1 Pro (ISO)](https://www.keychron.uk/collections/keychron-uk-iso-layout-keyboards/products/keychron-q1-pro-qmk-via-wireless-custom-mechanical-keyboard-iso-layout-collection?variant=44673713012906) - £159.00 (barebones), £176.00 (with switches and keycaps)

[image]

This is going to be your best, no-compromises all-rounder. It's got every feature you could want in a classic keyboard, and at a pretty reasonable price.

- Classic 75% layout, with a small knob
- Full CNC aluminum construction
- Supports wired or wireless (Bluetooth 5.1) operation, with an included 4000 mAh mattery
- Hot-swappable switches; includes either Keychron Red or Keychron Brown switches in the assembled version, with your choice of keycaps
- Fully programmable using QMK & VIA, rather than proprietary software
- No palm rest included, can be added later if you change your mind
- ISO layout; included keycaps are UK-specific. Includes keycaps for both Windows and macOS.

## [Epomaker TH80 Pro](https://epomaker.com/products/epomaker-th80?variant=40312374034505) - [£65.99 (barebones)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/EPOMAKER-Swappable-Mechanical-South-Facing-Compatible/dp/B0BMPP6YXG/), [£85.99 (with switches and keycaps)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/EPOMAKER-Bluetooth-Mechanical-Keyboard-Flamingo/dp/B0BGXD2F3Y/)

[image]

The build quality on this keyboard isn't quite as fancy as the Keychron Q1 Pro—it's a plastic chassis, and the included keycaps are PBT with dye-sublimation instead of double-shot ABS—but for the price, it's real hard to complain. In any case, it should still beat your K70 by a mile (although it's not liquid proof :P).

- Classic 75% layout, with a small knob
- Plastic chassis with steel plate
- Supports wired or wireless (Bluetooth 5.0 *or 2.4 GHz with a dongle*) operation, with an included 3000 mAh battery
- Hot-swappable switches; includes either Epomaker Flamingo (Linear), Epomaker Budgerigar (Tactile), or Gateron Pro Yellow (Linear) switches in the assembled version, with your choice of keycaps
- Fully programmable with support for up to three layers, but requires proprietary software
- No palm rest
- ISO layout; included keycaps are *not* UK-specific. If this is a dealbreaker, you can always go with the barebones kit and choose your own switches/keycaps.

## Honorable mentions

- SKYLOONG GK75 Triple-Mode for high customizability; however, the wireless version (triple mode) doesn't seem to come in an ISO layout
- Ajazz AK820 for being extremely cheap at $50; however, I can't find an ISO layout
- Wooting, the reigning "best gaming keyboard"; however, the 80HE (TKL layout) is still in the preorder stage and doesn't support wireless